# How to verify the list of Block Producers and Validators of Nth epoch in Near

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol, consensus

https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/docs/architecture/how/epoch.md#how-do-we-pick-the-next-validators

> How do we pick the next validators?
> in the last block of the epoch T, we look at the accounts that have highest stake and we pick them to become validators in T+2.
> We are deciding on validators for T+2 (and not T+1) as we want to make sure that validators have enough time to prepare for block production and validation (they have to download the state of shards etc).
> For more info on how we pick validators please look at nomicon.

In Near blockchain according to documentation in the last block of N-2 epoch is formed a list of 100 producers and validators ordered by the biggest stakes. This list is applied to the Nth epoch and produce/validate all 43,200 blocks of this epoch, as well as forms in the last block of Nth epoch a new list for epoch N+2.
Based on this, the validator list for the N+2 epoch should be published in the last block of the epoch, but there is no validator list in the last block of the epoch.
How to verify the list of Block Producers and Validators of Nth epoch in Near?

I get the last block of the epoch with height #89913095

```
curl --location 'https://rpc.mainnet.near.org' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": "dontcare",
    "method": "block",
    "params": {
        "block_id": 89913095
        
    }
}'
```

And I expect this block to contain a list of validators with their public keys for the N+2 epoch

Comment: I think the best answer you can get is the actual code, as pointed out here: https://near.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/295558-pagoda.2Fcore/topic/list.20of.20validators.20for.20epoch/near/351111168